# Rest API for bitbucket branch Sync

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

Need Rest API to Sync branches in Bitbucket (Cloud) without merge pull request. Cannot find in API documentation.
Is there any rest API for syncing branches?

Please help on above query (high priority).

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this? I need this